Remove the space after a link in Typst
When I use the #link function in Typst, it inserts a space afterward. Is there a way to not have this?
For example:
#link("www.hello.com")[hello]hi
prints hello hi (with hello as a link) but I want it to print hellohi (with hello as a link but hi as regular text).
I've played around with inserting stuff like #h(-2pt) but this seems very inelegant.
Thanks!

I have checked your code example in an empty Typst document (without a template) in Typst 0.12 and 0.11.1 and there was never a space. Does your template by any chance define show rules for links that include a space?

Oh man, how embarrassing - I had a #show link statement buried at the top of my document that was the cause of this behavior. It works as expected without that statement! Thanks for your help!!!!! I feel like an idiot hahaha
